# Grails vs. Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grails

Any dynamics in the community that would let you chose Grails or Rails?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81830/rails-or-grails

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Previous related questions can be found here:

[Rails or Grails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81830/rails-or-grails)

[Learning Ruby on Rails any good for Grails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087/learning-ruby-on-rails-any-good-for-grails)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283935/what-technology-asp-php-joomla-rails-grails-for-a-website-from-scratch

[Is Grails worth it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397228/is-grails-worth-it)

[Is Grails (now) worth it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055396/is-grails-now-worth-it)